# Livereload doesn't work on visual studio 2017 cordova project with using jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, cordova, jquery-mobile, livereload

I run cordova blank project with reference to [this document written by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/build-your-first-app?view=toolsforcordova-2017).

When I add scripts of jQuery and jQuery mobile on the bottom of body section of index.html, live reload stopped working.
The simulate browser doesn't reload automatically after I save index.html.

Can you help me about this issue?

- Version information

  ```
  Cordova: 6.3.1
  jQuery: 1.8.0
  jQuery mobile: 1.4.5
  ```
- index.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

  <title>BlankCordovaApp1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Page -->
  <div data-role="page">
      <p>Page 1 index</p>
      <p>text aaa</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Page 2 -->
  <div data-role="page">
      <p>Page 2</p>
  </div>


  <div class="app">
      <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
      <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
          <p class="event listening">Connecting to your device...</p>
          <p class="event received">Connecting Complete!!</p>
      </div>
      <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-shadow ui-btn-small">button</button>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Verify that the file addresses are correct.

Comment: I made sure these path about js and css and can use jQuery mobile features and css while running app by reload browser manually. when I remove that code "<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>", livereload works. I wanna use livereload while  using that code.